# CloudFormation syntax for ParameterOverrides

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm getting stuck on overriding multiple parameters within a CloudFormation that is passing them to CodePipeline.

I can successful override a single parameter like this:

```
ParameterOverrides: "{ \"StageName\": \"stage\" }"
```

But when I try this:

```
ParameterOverrides: '{ "StageName": "prod", "EnvValue", "prod" }'
```

I have also tried these combinations:

```
ParameterOverrides: "{\"StageName\": \"prod\", \"EnvValue\", \"prod\"}"
```

Codepipeline throws an error of: ParameterOverrides property is not valid

I have looked at this help article a half a dozen times and it seems I'm following the format to the T.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-parameter-override-functions.html

What am I missing? Does anyone have this working in a CloudFormation template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, fat fingered.
I put this:

```
ParameterOverrides: "{\"StageName\": \"prod\", \"EnvValue\", \"prod\"}"
```

and it should have been this:

```
ParameterOverrides: "{\"StageName\": \"prod\", \"EnvValue\": \"prod\"}"
```

NOTICE: the missing colon on after the second key.

Comment: Had a similar issue, but was missing a comma between two properteis.

Answer (score 4):

When dealing with embedded JSON in your YAML, the folded (`>`) or literal (`|`) block style, rather than a quoted string, will increase clarity. So something like:

```
ParameterOverrides: >
  {
    "StageName": "prod",
    "EnvValue": "prod"
  }
```

This will let you see the actual JSON without quite as much noise from the backslash escapes in the way. This can be seen in the "Example Create Stack B Stage" section of the page you linked to (it uses the literal block style with `|`). The difference between `|` and `>` can be seen on the [YAML Multiline](https://yaml-multiline.info/) site.